# Write to GoogleSheet via API with Java

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-sheets-api

I am trying to write a value to a cell with Google Sheet API with Java.
For reading I used guide from [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/java#step_3_set_up_the_sample) which worked fine for me.

For writing to Google Sheet I use:

```
service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId, "Sheet1!A4:H", response).execute();
```

This function outputs the following error while run:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

As a Authentication Scope I am using

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);
```

Comment: Have you check your [`client-secret.json`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing#installed-applications) file? Or used the proper [scopes](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing) in authorizing request for Spreadsheet. I hope this helps.

Comment: Try to use approval_prompt=false when build the auth flow.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot I have recreated client-secret.json but nothing changed. Regarding the scopes - am I using the right one as I stated in original message?

Comment: @hoozecn Can you explain more regarding the flow please?

Comment: `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("force")
                .build();
`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently there were several issues together:

1. Delete credentials that were stored at /Users/XXX/.credentials.
2. Change Scopes to SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS.
3. Google Sheet Share and Edit options at on Sheet itself.

Now it works!
Thank you guys for help

Comment: Sir, you saved a life here.

Comment: Deleting Creds and Changing the scope worked for me. Thank you Alex :)

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. I resolved the problem that was in the scope.
I just changed

```
SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS.READONLY
```

To

```
 SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS
```

And it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

The Java API must be used in an interactive way, if you're running this on a server that can't pop up a web-browser (which will let you approve an OAuth dialog), then the authentication flow doesn't get proper credentials and won't work.

While running this, do you see a browser pop up to approve an OAuth dialog?  If not, you're likely running in a headless session and will need some other means to get the user's credentials.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing "Sheet1!A4:H" with A4:H