# Writing in Google Sheets API v4 using Python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I have been trying really hard to do my code working just by reading examples, but i can't find an example about the correct way of writting in a sheet using the API.

Here's the part of my code that it isn't working:

```
def comprar(producto,cantidad):
credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
discoveryUrl = ('https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?'
                'version=v4')
service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=http,
                          discoveryServiceUrl=discoveryUrl)

spreadsheetId = '1oN1WkdXSYIlsgjFKZX1YolwajNflqAgE20w8vcRaY8Y'
row = searchInCol("A",producto)
target = "Inventario!"+"J"+str(row)
values = [
    [
        # Cell values to be inputed...
        int(cantidad)
    ],
# Additional rows ...
]
body = {"values":values}
print("Entra")

#THIS ISN'T WOKRING
result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=target,
valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body=body).execute()
print("entra")
```

The function that is not working is the comprar one, the console says: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes". I can't even understand what it means. 
By the way here you have the function get_credentials():

```
def get_credentials():
"""Gets valid user credentials from storage.

If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

Returns:
    Credentials, the obtained credential.
"""
home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
    os.makedirs(credential_dir)
credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                               'sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json')

store = Storage(credential_path)
credentials = store.get()
if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
    flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
    if flags:
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
    else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
        credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
    print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
return credentials
```

And here I have all the modules imported:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
import time
```

If anyone could explain me a little bit of what's wrong and an example of a working code for writing in a google sheet using python and the API, it would be really helpful. And also, if you need any more information about the code, please tell me. (I'm just a noob student.)

*Edit:*
I've changed this:

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
```

To this:

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
```

But it keeps throwing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 210, in <module>
  comprar(pro,cnt)
  File "quickstart.py", line 196, in comprar
valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body=body).execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 838, in execute
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1oN1WkdXSYIlsgjFKZX1YolwajNflqAgE20w8vcRaY8Y/values/Inventario%21J1?alt=json&valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you go through the OAuth2 flow again after modifying your SCOPES?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Not sure the best way, but you might try renaming the `~/.credentials` directory, or perhaps the most recently modified file in that directory.

Comment: It's working now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, make sure that you **enable all the API** that you used here especially the **Sheets API** in your Developers Console.

The error `"Request had insufficient authentication scopes"` that you receive is an error in the OAuth 2.0 token provided in the request that specify the [scopes](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing) that you are using are insufficient for accessing the requested data.

So make sure you follow the steps here on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing) on how to Authorize your request with OAuth.

For more information, you can check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520782/write-to-googlesheet-via-api-with-java).

Comment: So, I've changed this

Comment: Sorry, I've changed this:                                                                            SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'