# google sheets api v4 PHP Quickstart Writing to a single range

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I can read my Google Sheet Doc use this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php

quickstart.php:

```
 <?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Sheets API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS_READONLY)
));

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
  } else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
  }
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
  return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
  $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
  if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv('HOMEDRIVE') . getenv('HOMEPATH');
  }
  return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

// Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:

$spreadsheetId = 'myfileid';
$range = 'Class Data!A2';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();

if (count($values) == 0) {
  print "No data found.\n";
} else {
  print "Name, Major:\n";
  foreach ($values as $row) {
    // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
    printf("%s, %s\n", $row[0], $row[4]);
  }
}
```

All is Ok. I can read my Google Sheet Doc. But I need have only one additional  possibility: writing to a single range. I added to end of quickstart.php this code:

```
    $values = array(
    array(
5
    ),
    // Additional rows ...
);
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(array(
  'values' => $values
));
$params = array(
  'valueInputOption' => $valueInputOption
);
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range,
    $body, $params);
```

frome here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values

I have:
PHP Fatal error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

My Google Sheet Doc has permission for redact/modify. I need have  writing to a single range. What is mean this error? Please help me modify quickstart.php.

Comment: Check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520782). Try to change `SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS.READONLY` to `SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS`. This is an error in the OAuth 2.0 token provided in the request specifies [scopes](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing) that are insufficient for accessing the requested data. Make sure that you use the correct and all necessary scope by checking this [Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing#AboutAuthorization). Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Abielita. Thanks for help. I make: SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS . But it is not help. It is strange. php quickstart.php Name, Major:
MY DATA (A2)
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

Comment: No no. It is better)) I delete .credentials. New error easy: "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT".

Answer (score 0):

Change the scopes to `Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS` [check](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Sheets.html),

also try this

```
$params = array(
  'valueInputOption' => $valueInputOption
);
```

to [check](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption)

```
 $params = array(
      'valueInputOption' => 'USER_ENTERED'
    );
```